# Light Weight Tool to find all the line segment in a polygon for KML files

Tags: postgis, kml, software-recommendations

I have KML file and .csv file in google's fusion table. First file has polygon geometry of city with number of deaths. Second file has line geometry of roads with data like total traffic.

What I want to find is all the lines(roads) lying inside polygon(states). And then sum up total traffic for all those lines.

For example:

```
Table 1  
City       Deaths   geometry 
Melbourne  50         polygon_geom1

Table 2
road_name  total_vehicles geometry
Victoria_Road  70           line_geom1
Pink_road       79           line_geom2

So if line_geom1 and line_geom2 lies inside polygon_geom1 then Sum_Vechicle=70+79=149.
```

I see a lot of tools like postgresql and all but they are very heavy tools and I have to learn them . Is there anything simple which I can do.

Answer (score 1):

There are many software packages that will do this standard GIS operation. Most will easily import KML files.

If you prefer a graphical interface, QGIS is a good option. Load the two layers, and then use the Intersection tool in Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools. That will create a new layer, and you can sum up the total traffic.

If you prefer a Python-based solution, try [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely).

R also has many tools that will do these operations.

You will also need to think about what you want to do with partial matches. For example, you may want to match only roads that are completely within the polygon or those that intersect the polygon.